# QTableWidget comboboxes add too slowly

Tags: qt

I have a QTableWidget with 5000-10000 rows. It populates with data almost instantly (despite having a small custom drawn chart in one column which is created during population). But I have a problem with comboboxes. Comboboxes creation and population is almost instant too but adding them to a cell takes too much time (about 70 comboboxes per second). The problem is exactly adding comboboxes to my QTableWidget (not creating or populating them with data). If I comment population code nothing changes.

```
QComboBox* combo = new QComboBox(); // instant
// commented population code - it was instant too
ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(row, col, combo); // very slow
```

Is it possible to make them add quickly or should I avoid using comboboxes in QTableWidget? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Using cell widgets is quite heavy. Consider using an item delegate instead. Maybe you need to subclass the table widget to get access to the protected indexFromItem / itemFromIndex

Comment: Also considering them 'on the fly' when they scroll into view, in stead of creating them all at once during initialization.